# Java Apache PDFBox - Encryption not deterministic

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I have the following code.

```
public byte[] encryptPdf(byte[] pdf, String password) throws IOException {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
   try (PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
      AccessPermission accessPermission = new AccessPermission();
      StandardProtectionPolicy protectionPolicy = new 
      StandardProtectionPolicy(null, password, accessPermission);
      protectionPolicy.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
      protectionPolicy.setPermissions(accessPermission);
      pdDocument.protect(protectionPolicy);
      baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      pdDocument.save(baos);
   }
   return baos.toByteArray();
}

@Test
public void shouldEncryptedPDFEquals() {
   byte[] pdf = IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.pdf"));

   byte[] firstEncryption = encryptPdf(pdf, "token");
   byte[] secondEncryption = encryptPdf(pdf, "token");

   assertThat(firstEncryption.length, is(secondEncryption.length));
}
```

Inside a test i will check encrypted documents if there are equals.

The Problem is, that the generates byte array is not deterministic.

If i call the method multiple times, the array length are not ever equals. The assert failed. But not for all types of pdf files.

Is there a bug inside the Apache PDFBox library?

Comment: Why do you expect an encrypted ciphertext to be deterministic? Many encryption schemes are randomized by design

Comment: Right, but PDFBox produce for many pdf (example) files the same output for me on multiple encryptions. IMO -> that is not what its inventor had in mind either if there is no deterministic desired

Comment: Could be a file with missing /ID. In that case a new ID is created that is influenced by the current time. So please attach your unencrypted PDF.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr, thats it.